# Is it possible to use <Pause> in TwiML for Programmable SMS?

Tags: python, flask, twilio, twilio-twiml, pause

I'm new to Twilio. Is it possible to use < Pause > within TwiML for Programmable SMS? I see that it's possible for TwiML Voice. I've looked all over the place online but can't find a straight answer.

My use case is that I'm trying to build a chatbot app with Flask/Twilio that leaves realistic pauses between responses. For example, if I send my Twilio phone number a text, I want the app to pause for 30 seconds before replying. At the moment, the chatbot works just as I need it to **except** that it replies immediately.

I've tried time.sleep() within my Flask endpoint function, but I think that causes some sort of timeout whenever I deploy my Flask app locally and access it with ngrok. I say that because if I use time.sleep(), the reply from the app via sms never comes through.

Hope that all made at least a bit of sense.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `<Pause>` in SMS TwiML, it's a voice only TwiML verb.

Twilio webhooks have a [15 second timeout](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-connection-overrides), so sleeping for too long will cause an error and the response won't be sent.

If you want to delay a message by 30 seconds, I would recommend finding a way to schedule a job within your application. Then, instead of responding with a `<Message>` in the TwiML response, send back an empty `<Response>`. Meanwhile, queue a job to be executed 30 seconds later and [use the REST API to send the message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#create-a-message-resource).